# Why am i getting "Unexpected token <" errors in angular 2?

Tags: angular

So I'm building an angular 2 app, it's simple. contains 1 page and a login screen. here is my file structure:

```
├── node_modules
├── app
|    ├── app.component.ts
|    ├── boot.ts  
|    ├── pages
|        |── dashboard
|            |── dashboard.components.ts
|            |── dashboard.html
|        |── login
|            |── login.components.ts
|            |── login.html
|            |── auth.ts
```

and my files:
app.component.ts:

```js
import {Component OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ,Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {LoginComponent} from './pages/login/login.component';
import {DashboardComponent} from './pages/dashboard/dashboard.component'
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template:`
        <div class="wrapper">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>`
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/',name: 'Home',redirectTo: ['Dashboard'] },
    { path: '/login',name:'Login',component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '/dashboard',name:'Dashboard',component: DashboardComponent,}
])
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    private userAuthenticated = false;
    constructor(
        private _router: Router
    ){}
    ngOnInit(){
        if(!this.userAuthenticated){
            this._router.navigate(['Login']);
        }
    }
}
```

dashboard.component.ts:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl:'app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html'
})
export class DashboardComponent{
    public message = "Hello";
}
```

login.components.ts:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgForm}    from 'angular2/common';
@Component({
    selector:"login",
    templateUrl:'app/pages/login/login.html',
})
export class LoginComponent{
}
```

EVERYTHING at this point works great. Until I import auth.ts login.components.ts. Once I do this I get these errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <U @ system.src.js:4597o.execute @ system.src.js:4597i @ system.src.js:4597n @ system.src.js:4597execute @ system.src.js:4597y @ system.src.js:4597w @ system.src.js:4597p @ system.src.js:4597h @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:1511lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:1523lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:1494(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:243run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:1305
    angular2-polyfills.js:138 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
        Evaluating http://local.intranet/auth
        Error loading http://local.intranet/app/boot.js
```

Here is what login.components.ts looks like now:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgForm}    from 'angular2/common';
import {Auth} from 'auth';
@Component({
    selector:"login",
    templateUrl:'app/pages/login/login.html',
})
export class LoginComponent{
    login = new Auth("","");
    onSubmit(){console.log(this.login)};
}
```

and auth.ts looks like this:

```js
export class Auth {
    constructor(
        public userName: string,
        public password: string
    ) {  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm using.

Comment: Did you add the router bundle?

Comment: Like I said everything works until I import auth.ts

Comment: Well, hard to say without looking at the config. As you see in the error is calling `app/boot.js` and `auth` (with no extension and with no `app`), so most likely your `auth` file is out of the config. Try importing `app/auth`, if that works is problem in your config.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in your login.component.ts:

```
import {Auth} from './auth';
```

instead of

```
import {Auth} from 'auth';
```

As I understand, this is the way the ES6 import syntax works. when importing from a module name "not a path", the module has to be registered beforehand using System.register(). So, when you import 'auth', the system will look for a registered module called 'auth'.

On the other hand, if you import from  './some/path' relative to your file, the module will be imported without having to be registered globally.

[look in the SystemJS docs for more info](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/production-workflows.md)

Comment: Can you explain to me the need for the "./"? Is this needed when importing any custom components?

Comment: yes, it's needed. You could also use '../' relatively to your file. I added some explanation. I hope it helped.

Comment: It's also needed in following scenario `import {Auth} from './../providers/auth';`